# Overlap Analysis of 3 layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features

I am trying to calculate the overlap area between features of three different vector layers in QGIS 3.22, but the overlap analysis tool only calculates overlap between two layers.

For example, I would like to know the overlap area between the distribution maps of three species.

With the overlap analysis tool, it is possible to have two overlay layers, but the tool calculates the overlap between the input layer and each overlay layer separately. How can I calculate the overlap area between the three layers?

Answer (score 2):

The Overlap Analysis can be used with multiple layers. As result you will have the shape of the input layer with additional fields containing the area and the percentage for each overlay layer:

[image]

Comment: It doesnt work in model builder for some reason, but It does when executed manually, weird